# automatically realign the tooltip when the pointer is on the right side of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to make the tooltip automatically place to the left side of the pointer when the pointer hovering the right side of the page?

here is my html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="img">
<a href="html/takraw.html" class="tooltip">
<img class="img" src="images/sepak-takraw.jpg" alt="img">
<span>
  <div class="tooltipbox">
    <h2>Sepak Takraw</h2>
  </div>
 </span>
 </a>
 <div class="desc">Sepak Takraw</div>
 </div>
 <div class="img">
  <a href="#" class="tooltip">
  <img src="images/archery.jpg" alt="img"/>
   <span>
   <div class="tooltipbox">
    <h2>Archery</h2>
  </div>
   </span>
  </a> 
  <div class="desc">Archery</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

style.css

```
div.img {
margin: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
float: left;
width: 240px;
} 
div.img img {
width: 240px;
height:200px;
}
.container {
background:white; padding: 20px; 
position: relative;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.tooltipbox {
width: 400px;
min-height: 400px;
background: white;
opacity: .95;
padding: 20px;
}
.tooltip {
text-decoration:none;
position:relative;      
}
.tooltip span {
display:none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
display:block;
position:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

script.js

```
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
var x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px',
    y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px';


for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
    tooltips[i].style.top = y;
    tooltips[i].style.left = x;
}  
};
```

I want to make my tooltip to place to the left side of the the pointer when the pointer hover the right side of the page. how to do this?

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/t5atf4z1/

Comment: e.clientX anf e.clientY should be relative to tooltip box height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check tooltips right side position is out of document.

like this

```
tooltips[i].style.left = ((e.clientX + 20) + tooltips[i].clientWidth < document.body.clientWidth)?x:(e.clientX + 20)-tooltips[i].clientWidth+'px';
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t5atf4z1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
var x = (e.clientX - 450) + 'px',
    y = (e.clientY - 450) + 'px';


for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
    tooltips[i].style.top = y;
    tooltips[i].style.left = x;
}  
};
```

```css
div.img {
margin: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
float: left;
width: 240px;
} 
div.img img {
width: 240px;
height:200px;
}
.container {
background:white; padding: 20px; 
position: relative;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.tooltipbox {
width: 400px;
min-height: 400px;
background: white;
opacity: .95;
padding: 20px;
}
.tooltip {
text-decoration:none;
position:relative;      
}
.tooltip span {
display:none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
display:block;
position:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="img">
<a href="html/takraw.html" class="tooltip">
<img class="img" src="images/sepak-takraw.jpg" alt="img">
<span>
  <div class="tooltipbox">
    <h2>Sepak Takraw</h2>
  </div>
 </span>
 </a>
 <div class="desc">Sepak Takraw</div>
 </div>
 <div class="img">
  <a href="#" class="tooltip">
  <img src="images/archery.jpg" alt="img"/>
   <span>
   <div class="tooltipbox">
    <h2>Archery</h2>
  </div>
   </span>
  </a> 
  <div class="desc">Archery</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: clientx and clienty should be relative to width and height of tooltip box

Comment: sir thank you for the reply but my problem is how to place the tooltip automatically to the left side of the pointer when the pointer is on the right side of the image, i mean on the right side of the page so that the tooltip can seen and cannot be cut of... Hope you understand what I mean...

Comment: Please check this link to a working code [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/d0kwo0d0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px',
        width = document.body.clientWidth,
        toolTipWidth = 400;
    if (width - e.clientX > toolTipWidth) {
        x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px';
    } else {
        x = (e.clientX - 40 - toolTipWidth) + 'px';
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
        tooltips[i].style.top = y;
        tooltips[i].style.left = x;
    }
};
```

Check the length between your mouse and the right edge of the browser.If the length is less than the `ToolTip`'s width, change your `x` value with conditional statement.

Since you have a specific width of the ToolBox ,I hard coded it into js file.

I'm not sure it is the best, but it works

Answer (score 0):

> I think this will solve your problem:
>       [Working code][1]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/d0kwo0d0/1/
```